# cURL works in CLI, but not in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, command-line-interface

This is the code I am using:

```
curl -k https://www.ashleydirect.com/graphics/ad_images/T908-6.jpg
```

This works fine (the "-k" flag is necessary for it to work or it times out)

I then use this code in PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://www.ashleydirect.com/graphics/ad_images/T908-6.jpg");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And it times out -- I've tried a ton of variations, but `$result` is always **false**.

This is the PHP cURL information when I do phpinfo():

> **cURL support**  enabled
>   **cURL Information**  7.38.0
>   **Age**   3
>   **Features**
>   **AsynchDNS** No
>   **Debug** No
>   **GSS-Negotiate** No
>   **IDN**   Yes
>   **IPv6**  Yes
>   **Largefile** Yes
>   **NTLM**  Yes
>   **SPNEGO**    No
>   **SSL**   Yes
>   **SSPI**  No
>   **krb4**  No
>   **libz**  Yes
>   **CharConv**  No
>   **Protocols** dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
>   **Host**  x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   **SSL Version**   OpenSSL/1.0.1e
>   **ZLib** Version  1.2.3

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the information from `curl_getinfo($ch)`:

```
array (
  'url' => 'https://www.ashleydirect.com/graphics/ad_images/T908-6.jpg',
  'content_type' => NULL,
  'http_code' => 0,
  'header_size' => 0,
  'request_size' => 0,
  'filetime' => -1,
  'ssl_verify_result' => 1,
  'redirect_count' => 0,
  'total_time' => 59.27538100000000298450686386786401271820068359375,
  'namelookup_time' => 0.00975999999999999957867036215475309290923178195953369140625,
  'connect_time' => 0.05170500000000000095923269327613525092601776123046875,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0,
  'size_upload' => 0,
  'size_download' => 0,
  'speed_download' => 0,
  'speed_upload' => 0,
  'download_content_length' => -1,
  'upload_content_length' => -1,
  'starttransfer_time' => 0,
  'redirect_time' => 0,
  'certinfo' => 
  array (
  ),
  'primary_ip' => '65.207.240.29',
  'primary_port' => 443,
  'local_ip' => '172.24.32.132',
  'local_port' => 54461,
  'redirect_url' => '',
)
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Response from `curl_error`:

```
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.ashleydirect.com:443
```

---

**UPDATE 3 - Solution**

I wanted to clearly put the solution I came up with, thanks to @Valery Viktorovsky who pointed out they only accept TLS 1.0.

The solution, then was to add this:

```
// Set to TLS 1.0 (CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
```

[More information here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: You tried `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, how about with `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` for the purpose of debugging only?

Comment: @Scuzzy I have tested, no difference.

Comment: Are you testing the CLI version from the same server as the PHP version?

Comment: @Willian No, not behind a proxy, we are behind a firewall, but that's the same for CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your php code is fine. Do a `curl_getinfo($ch)` and `curl_error($ch)` after`curl_exec` to see the response code returned by the server.

Update: I tested ashleydirect.com SSL certificate and it supports only TLS 1.0. So make sure your php version supports TLSv1.0.

Comment: Correct, no response code, I posted the information above.

Comment: @Kerry, please try to add `print_r(curl_error($ch))` command after exec.

Comment: Added to the info above, and here: `Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.ashleydirect.com:443`

Comment: Wow -- that was it, TLS 1.0 -- specifically. Thank you so much -- how did you test it and figure out what it supported (for future reference for myself)

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me, both the command line without `-k` and the PHP code.

If for some reason it times out you can set a bigger timeout:

```
// if it times out on establishing the connection
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);   // seconds
// if it times out while waiting for the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);          // seconds
```

Also, the call `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)` is usually accompanied by:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

to get the complete effect.

Comment: It is timing out after 60 seconds, I tried with VERIFYHOST as well, same thing. Good to know it works for you...

Comment: The command line `curl`, with or without `-k` starts almost instantly and needs about 12 seconds to download the file. This [pastie](http://pastie.org/10362528) contains the `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` after the PHP version completed the transfer. I'm using the exact code you posted. It is probably a connection issue on your side.

Comment: Thank you -- do you have any idea what type of connection could start that? the curl -k works for me instantly as well, what would affect PHP but not CLI?

Comment: Different versions of `curl`; different settings; different SSL/TLS libraries. I don't know. Try different values for `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION`, maybe it helps.

Comment: I saw the question updates now. `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` is the solution. Try the values with `TLS`.